# Express throws "TypeError : Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined at Function.app.use"

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have been trying to use the session middleware on Express framework.The exact line with the error is

```
if (fn.handle && fn.set) mount_app=fn;
```

Currently the app.js file contains

```
var express = require('express'); 
var session= require('express-session'); 
var app = express();
```

Accordingly I have used below

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
res.locals.session = req.session;
next();
 }
```

The reason given for errors of above type, in one of these forums was that the variable was being used before being defined. Could someone suggest how this could be done, or what is wrong with the above ordering.

Comment: `fn` is `undefined` at that point. Where does `fn` come from?

Comment: the first line comes from a different file called application.js which is part of the framework.The above line comes under app.use=function(route,fn){ . . . }

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted thus far. Are you sure that your application isn't referenced in the resulting stack trace?

Comment: one of the lines in the stack trace says " at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node\nodetest1\app.js 45:5) " .The application is residing in nodetest1.

Comment: I am having the same problem.... I know that this is late, but I would appreciate it if someone could help me out